# Will clangs custom int size feature ever get added to gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, extint

I was wondering whether clang's new amazing custom size (things like 13-bit int, or 70-bit int, etc.) will get added to gcc.

Comment: Depends it's being considered by the ISO WG14 C Language Committee see: http://blog.llvm.org/2020/04/the-new-clang-extint-feature-provides.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No most likely, it won't. That is because `clang` uses `llvm` as its compiling backend, and `gcc` doesn't. The `llvm` backend is what allows `clang` to pull off that feat. LLVM allows from `1` to `16,777,215` bit ints.

Comment: Even with a 16,777,215 bit int folk will still complain it's not large enough!

Comment: @Bathsheba **Yes!** We _will_ :-)

Comment: Depends it's being considered by the ISO WG14 C Language Committee see: http://blog.llvm.org/2020/04/the-new-clang-extint-feature-provides.html  So if GCC intends to follow the standard ...

Comment: Imagine having a 2MB integer.

Comment: @Ayxan: I'm wondering what `int a[2];` as automatic storage would do to your stack?

Comment: @Bathsheba Stack size can be changed on a per-compilation-unit basis. Just make it large enough 

Comment: @Bathsheba Doesn't seem to work at all https://godbolt.org/z/orAgnH

Comment: @Bathsheba in fact, I could not use the 16,777,215 bit integer in any meaningful way. Even if it's on the heap. It simply segfaults.

Comment: @Ayxan -- I don't know why that is, but when I built clang 11 from source, it worked just fine.

Comment: @xilpex I m noticing the gcc s golang frontend supports golang big integers.

Answer (score 2):

Well. C23 has finally implemented them as `_BigInt`